# On proving NP-completeness by reduction to 3-partition problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Consider a problem $X$ can be reduced to 3-partition problem. So, when 3-partition has a solution then $X$ has a solution. But if 3-partition does not have a solution, they $X$ may or may not have a solution. In this case, is it legal to say that the problem $X$ is np-complete?

Comment: Problems don't have solutions, problem *instances* do.  You seem to be confused with the fundamentals; our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/845#845) can help.

Comment: It is not illegal to make false mathematical statements.

Comment: @TomVanDerZanden [Put the statement down. Step away from the statement](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/50994/472). Sorry, couldn't resist... :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't prove **NP**-completeness.

1. The thing you describe isn't a reduction.  It must be that the instance of $X$ has a solution if, and only if, the instance of 3-partition has a solution.
2. Reducing $X$ to 3-partition just proves that $X$ is in **NP**.  To prove completeness, you need to reduce an **NP**-complete problem to $X$.

I suggest that you revise the basic concepts from your class notes, textbook or online resources.

Comment: Just to add something to the previous answer (i can't comment yet :)) the reduction you are searching must be a polynomial time function (you can find some time expensive reductions from an Np-Complete problem to your problem X, however those are not making the NP-Complete problem any simpler!)